# Tableau SAML (Your account or password is incorrect)

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, tableau-api, saml-2.0

I'm trying to enable additional authentication methods to Tableau Online by adding Keycloak as IDP (SAML). I followed the following steps

1. Export metadata from Tableau Online
2. Created a user in keycloak with the same username as the username found in Tableau
3. Created a Realm and Client on Keycloak and imported MetaData exported from Tableau Online
4. Added Mapping in Tableau Client with "User Attribute" "username"
5. Exported metadata from Keycloak and inserted it in Tableau Online

When I try to test the connection, it redirects correctly to the Keycloak login page but after trying to log in and keycloak authenticates me, it redirects me back to Tableau online login page with an error:  (Your account or password is incorrect)

Any idea why this might be happening?